# How to use Thunderbird's address book in LibreOffice?

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, thunderbird, address-book

I'm using LibreOffice (3.5) and Thunderbird (17.0) on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine and store my contacts with Thunderbird. These contacts are organized in several address books. For each I get a *.mab-file* ([Mork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%28file_format%29)) in `/home/user/.thunderbird/xyxyxyxy.default/`. What's the finest and/or easiest option to access these contacts from LibreOffice?

I have already read that there should be an option to access the Thunderbird Address Book easily but Thunderbird does not appear as a data source in LibreOffice (File >> Wizards >> Address Data Source). The package `libreoffice-base` is already installed.

If possible, I want to prevent to export my contacts in another storage format.

Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TBird addressbook has never been implemented in the Canonical version of Libre/Open Office.

You need to UNINSTALL the version that ships with Ubuntu and install the version downloaded directly from the LO website.

[Here's how to do it](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?nodetect) select the correct .deb file format and download. Right click to install

[source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+question/165327)

Comment: In the long term I thought to switch to _Evolution_ and _Evolution Data Server_ and leave _.mab-files_ behind. But for the moment the database tool _Base_ and it's data source connector should do it. Thanks!